# Can't install ROS indigo in my Ubuntu 14.04.5 or ROS lunar in Windows WSL

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.5 installed in my computer. I have an NVIDIA GPU 920mx with it's driver and cuda, cudnn installed.
Now I am unable to install ROS indigo in it. I later tried to install ROS lunar in my Windows after installing WSL+UBUNTU 16.04. The same error comes up. So I think there is any problem in the ROS distro? The error comes up like following,

```
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-matplotlib-data all
1.5.1-1ubuntu1   Hash Sum mismatch Fetched 38.4 MB in 9min 14s (69.2 kB/s) E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5gui5_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtwebkit-opensource-src/libqt5webkit5_5.5.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/g++-5_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/x265/libx265-79_1.9-3_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtwebkit-source/libqtwebkit4_2.3.2-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3-dev_8.38-3.1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/matplotlib/python-matplotlib-data_1.5.1-1ubuntu1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
--fix-missing?
```

The error in Ubuntu 14.04.5 is following

### Heading

```
E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/log4cxx/liblog4cxx10_0.10.0-1.2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vtk/libvtk5.8_5.8.0-14.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-dev_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyside/python-pyside.qtcore_1.2.1-4build1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

after running command sudo apt-get update --fix-missing ,

```
   Ign file:  InRelease
Get:1 file:  Release.gpg [819 B]                                               
Get:2 file:  Release [574 B]                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en_US                                                   
Ign file:  Translation-en                                                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://mirror.clarkson.edu trusty InRelease                                
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://mirror.clarkson.edu trusty/main amd64 Packages                      
Get:4 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://mirror.clarkson.edu trusty/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [147 kB]         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Ign http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,931 B]  
Hit http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [67.2 kB]    
Hit http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Get:8 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [409 kB]        
Hit http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Ign http://mirror.clarkson.edu trusty/main Translation-en_US                   
Hit http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Ign http://mirror.clarkson.edu trusty/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [3,182 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [698 kB]
Get:11 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6,322 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:13 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [195 kB]   
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [199 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,800 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [641 kB]  
Get:17 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7,781 B]
Get:18 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,045 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [13.9 kB]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [195 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,958 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:22 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17.2 kB]
Get:23 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [437 kB]
Get:24 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.9 kB]
Get:25 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [985 kB] 
Get:26 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [17.0 kB]
Get:27 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [435 kB]
Get:28 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [15.3 kB]
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Fetched 5,710 kB in 48s (119 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

**Update: **

I was trying to install ROS indigo from Source, as `apt-get install` is not working for some reasons. But it is throwing , the following error

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install


 apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-qwt5-qt4] failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278299/can%27t-install-ros-indigo-in-my-ubuntu-14.04.5-or-ros-lunar-in-windows-wsl/) by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2017-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-28**:
What is the error that you are given when you try to install ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.5?

**Comment by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on 2017-12-28**:
E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.6-8ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://bd.arc

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-28**:
Please update your question with this error. Comments don't provide enough room.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-29**:
I updated this question with the information from your other question #q278324

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-29**:
I'm seeing hash mismatches and missing files: @sezan92: are you behind a proxy of some kind? This sort of problem is typically seen in case a proxy is improperly trying to cache / alter traffic for you.

**Comment by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on 2017-12-29**:
@gvdhoorn , I am using wifi router without any hotspot or proxy something ..how can I figure it out? I tried both in my ubuntu and Windows with WSL

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-29**:
You're forgetting your ISP might be using/forcing you to use a proxy.

I'm not saying this is the problem, but hash mismatches point to corrupted data.

Try using a different mirror and see if that changes anything. It may be a transient error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have solved the problem. The real problem was in apt-get mismatch. I had to solve it by upgrading apt verstion to 1.2.0. The details are mentioned [here](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/09/27/fixing-apt-hash-sum-mismatch-consistent-apt-repositories/)

---

Originally posted by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) with karma: 76 on 2017-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0